# Spark Hive Context hql issues in java - when running spark job in yarn

Tags: java, hive, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We have a spark application that is run with spark-submit in yarn. When running a

sparkHiveContext.hql("show databases") in java

getting the following exception

```
ClassLoaderResolver for class "" gave error on creation : {1} org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: ClassLoaderResolver for class "" gave error on creation : {1}
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getClassLoaderResolver(NucleusContext.java:1087)
at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.validatePropertyValue(PersistenceConfiguration.java:797)
at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.setProperty(PersistenceConfiguration.java:714)
at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.setPersistenceProperties(PersistenceConfiguration.java:693)
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:273)
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:247)
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:225)
```

down the stack trace i get

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
... 27 more caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
... 32 more Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
```

However..running my query in spark-sql console works. What is wrong with this.

Comment: ouch! i have exact same problem but in a different circumstance. This has something to do with hivemetastore.

Comment: So one of the reasons, i assume its happening is Spark is build with hive 0.13.a support and we are running hiveserver 0.14.0 or hive 1.0 now. Finally gave up and used a hive client connection and ran the hql statement

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that if you are packaging your spark app as a fat/uber jar the datanucleus libraries dont like it because there is a common pom.xml in each of the datanucleus dependecy jars which gets overwritten by one. You need to add them to classpath seperately.